# PowerShellのモジュールと関数の作り方：関数が認識されず呼び出せません．

Tags: powershell

PowerShellによるバッチ処理を学習中です．以下の現象で困っています．

### モジュールの宣言

メインの.ps1に以下のように書いております．

```
# Import
Import-Module "$($PSScriptRoot)\Module"
```

ModuleフォルダにはModule.psm1を配置し中に以下のような関数を書いています．

#### 動いてくれる関数 (英語版SOの見よう見まねです)

```
# Invoke command specifying command path and arguments.
Function Invoke-Command ($commandPath, $commandArguments)
{
  Try {
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = $commandPath
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = $commandArguments
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()
    [pscustomobject]@{
        StdOut = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        StdErr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
        ExitCode = $p.ExitCode
    }
  }
  Catch {
     exit
  }
}
```

こんな感じで使っています（あくまで該当箇所の抜粋）

```
# Saxon path（実行環境により修正する）
$saxon_path = 'D:\My_Documents/Java/SaxonPE10-6J/saxon-pe-10.6.jar'

# Java path（実行環境により修正する）
$java_path = 'C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jre1.8.0_261/bin'
$java_exec = $java_path + '/' + 'java.exe'
# ...
# Java command option & Saxon option/parameter
$java_option = ' -Xmx1024m '
$java_cmd_option = $java_option + " -jar " + $saxon_path + ' -xsl:' + $xsl_path + ' -it:' + $initial_template + ' -o:' + $out_bind_xml_path + ' PRM_XML_PATH=' + $data_xml_path

Write-Host "Start generating bind xml file from directory:'$data_xml_path' to file:'$out_bind_xml_path'" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black;

$start_date_time = Get-Date

$ret = Invoke-Command -commandPath $java_exec -commandArguments $java_cmd_option 
Write-Host $ret.StdOut
Write-Host $ret.StdErr
Write-Host 'XSLT processing return code:' $ret.ExitCode  -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
```

動作ログ（該当箇所のみ）

```
Start generating bind xml file from directory:'D:/My_Documents/XML2020/XXXXXX/docs/20211104-xml-php-data/xml-xxxxx-2021-08-yy-zz' to file:'C:/Users/toshi/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp214A.tmp'
XSLT processing return code: 0
Processing takes 0 minutes  2 seconds.
```

#### 動いてくれない関数 (こちらも英語版SOの見よう見まねです)

```
Function Invoke-Executable {
  # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371479/52277
  # Runs the specified executable and captures its exit code, stdout
  # and stderr.
  # Returns: custom object.
  # from http://www.codeducky.org/process-handling-net/ added timeout, using tasks
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
          [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
          [String]$commandPath,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
          [String]$commandArguments,
#          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
#          [String]$sVerb,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
          [Int]$TimeoutMilliseconds=1800000 #30min
      )
#     Write-Host $commandPath $commandArguments
  
  # Setting process invocation parameters.
  $oPsi = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
  $oPsi.CreateNoWindow = $true
  $oPsi.UseShellExecute = $false
  $oPsi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
  $oPsi.RedirectStandardError = $true
  $oPsi.FileName = $commandPath
  if (! [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($commandArguments)) {
      $oPsi.Arguments = $commandArguments
  }
#  if (! [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($sVerb)) {
#      $oPsi.Verb = $sVerb
#  }
  
  # Creating process object.
  $oProcess = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Process
  $oProcess.StartInfo = $oPsi

  # Starting process.
  [Void]$oProcess.Start()
  # Tasks used based on http://www.codeducky.org/process-handling-net/ 
  $outTask = $oProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
  $errTask = $oProcess.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();
  $bRet=$oProcess.WaitForExit($TimeoutMilliseconds)
  if (-Not $bRet)
  {
    $oProcess.Kill();
  #  throw [System.TimeoutException] ($commandPath + " was killed due to timeout after " + ($TimeoutMilliseconds/1000) + " sec ") 
  }
  $outText = $outTask.Result;
  $errText = $errTask.Result;
  if (-Not $bRet)
  {
      $errText =$errText + ($commandPath + " was killed due to timeout after " + ($TimeoutMilliseconds/1000) + " sec ") 
  }
  $oResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([Ordered]@{
#      "commandPath"  = $commandPath;
#      "Args"     = $cArgs -join " ";
      "ExitCode" = $oProcess.ExitCode;
      "StdOut"   = $outText;
      "StdErr"   = $errText
  })

  return $oResult
}
```

この関数はVSCodeのPowerShellで以下のエラーになってしまいます．

```
Start generating DITA topic path:'C:/Users/toshi/AppData/Local/Temp/e5a353ac-226e-4765-b23d-5d1e2bade516/topic'
Invoke-Executable: D:\My_Documents\XML2020\XXXXXX\docs\xml-php\build-tmc-xml-to-dita.ps1:129:8
Line |
 129 |  $ret = Invoke-Executable -commandPath $java_exec -commandArguments $j …
     |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Invoke-Executable' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
     | and try again.
```

このエラーは以下のような呼び出し記述の中で検出されています．

```
# Saxon path, Java pathは上記の使いまわしです．

# Java command option & Saxon option/parameter
$java_option = ' -Xmx1024m '  
$java_cmd_option = $java_option + " -jar " + $saxon_path + ' -t -xsl:' + $xsl_path + ' -s:' + $out_map_path + ' -o:' + $out_xml_path + ' -ea:on' + ' PRM_BIND_XML_URL=' + $bind_xml_url + ' PRM_OUTPUT_DIR_URL=' + $out_topic_dir_url

Write-Host "Start generating DITA topic path:'$out_topic_dir'" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black;
$start_date_time3 = Get-Date

$ret = Invoke-Executable -commandPath $java_exec -commandArguments $java_cmd_option 

Write-Host $ret.StdOut
Write-Host $ret.StdErr
Write-Host 'XSLT processing return code:' $ret.ExitCode  -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
```

ともかくモジュールも関数も初めて作ったので勝手がわかりません．
原因わかりましたらご教示ください．

VSCodeのPowerShellのPSVersionTableの情報は以下の通りです．

```
PS D:\My_Documents\XML2020\XXXXXX\docs\xml-php> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

大変失礼いたしました．自己解決しました．
フォルダに以前のVSCodeの設定（？）が残存していて影響を与えていたようです．".ionide"というフォルダを削除したらなんの問題もなく動いてくれました．